# PIN URL openstreetmap passing in latitude/longitude or some other platform

Tags: http, maps, openstreetmap

How to add a pin to my sample URL "http://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=9/-38.3266/144.8781", could not find it  ...`?

or some other platform, except google maps for passing easy my parameter ?

Comment: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Develop

Answer (score 4):

Open the share menu from the right panel and select "Include marker". A marker will appear which you can move to your selected position. Then just copy the URL from the share menu.

Example: https://www.openstreetmap.org/?mlat=-38.3653&mlon=144.9069#map=9/-38.3653/144.9069

The user interface for https://openstreetmap.org is described here: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Browsing